# Infinite topological space with cofinite topology is not Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I found a proof to the question, but mine is completely different (sort of). Is this correct?

> If $X$ were Hausdorff, then consider $u,v \in X$ with disjoint neighbourhoods $U, V$ that separates the points. But this would mean $(U \cap V)^c = \emptyset^c \iff U^c \cup V^c = X$, implying that the union of two finite sets equals $X$, an infinite set. So $X$ cannot possibly be Hausdorff.

The proof I read strategies by showing one of the disjoint open set cannot be in the complement of the other, which is a finite set. But this contradicts the other one being in the topology.

Comment: Your proof is perfectly correct, except for misspelling "Hausdorff" twice.

Comment: Not twice.... Thrice.... As you yourself corrected three times.

Comment: could you upvote mine if it also suits you? as a bit more rigorous .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This proof is certainly correct.

Comment: Since I appear to be unable to comment under the main post, may I ask what exactly you were unsure about in regards to the correctness?

Comment: upvote mine if it seems to have more rigor to it.

Answer (score 1):

A more concrete solution would be.

Let $x,y \in X$ have disjoint open neighborhoods, $U,V$ respectively.

Then

$$X \setminus U = \{p_1,...,p_m\}$$
$$X \setminus V = \{q_1,...,q_n\}$$

Then as $X$ is infinite, there exists some $z$ such that

$$z \neq p_i,q_j \space \text{for $1 \leq i \leq m$,$1 \leq j \leq n$}$$

This forces

$$z \in U \cap V$$

a contradiction to them being disjoint. Thus no disjoint neighborhoods exists under this  topology.